# Java Annotations: Using @Target(ElementType=METHOD) causes NPE

Tags: java, annotations, target

I am new to Java and I have a Problem concerning Java Annotations.
Short: The code works just fine, when I set **@Target** to **"TYPE"** and place the Annotation above the "SynCheck"-class. As soon as I change **@Target** to **"METHOD"** (as seen in the source code) and place the Annotation over the "isValid"-method, it causes a **NullPointerException** and I cannot figure out, why.
Please have a look on the code. (It is kind of a email syntax validator).

Main.java:

```
package emailvalid;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SynCheck validate = new SynCheck();

        Class<? extends SynCheck> c = validate.getClass();
        Annotation an = c.getAnnotation(InputVal.class);
        InputVal s = (InputVal)an;

        System.out.println(s.input());
        System.out.println("Syntax: " + SynCheck.isValid(s.input()));

    }
}
```

SynCheck.java:

```
package emailvalid;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class SynCheck {
    @InputVal(input = "example@domain.org")
    public static boolean isValid(String checkAddr)
    {
        final Pattern regexevalpat = Pattern.compile(
        "^((?=.{1,63}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\!\\#\\$\\%\\&\\’\\*\\+\\/\\=\\?\\^\\_\\`\\{\\|\\}\\~\\-]{0,})@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$");
        if (!regexevalpat.matcher(checkAddr).matches()) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
    }   
}
```

InputVal.java:

```
package emailvalid;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface InputVal {

    String input();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any help appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you release that `c.getAnnotation()` tries to get an annotation with `ElementType.TYPE` while you actually need `ElementType.METHOD`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not look for the annotation on the method. Only on the class.

```
 SynCheck validate = new SynCheck();
 Class<? extends SynCheck> c = validate.getClass();
 Annotation an = c.getAnnotation(InputVal.class);
 InputVal s = (InputVal)an;
```

That will only work if the InputVal annotation is on the SyncCheck class (as a type annotation).

When you move the annotation to the method the annotation will be null as it's no longer on the class...

If you want to put it on the method you need to change your code to:

```
 Class<? extends SynCheck> c = validate.getClass();
 Method m = c.getMethod("isValid");
 InputVal s = m.getAnnotation(InputVal.class);
```

A side comment is that you don't have to cast the annotation, you can retrieve it directly into the type it is.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. But now there is another exception, when I use Your code snipped, whether if I put the class name in the second argument fo getMethod or not : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: emailvalid.SynCheck.isValid()
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
 at emailvalid.Main.main(Main.java:11)

Comment: Yes, I had a suspicion there might be an issue finding the method like that. Try using getDeclaredMethod instead of getMethod...

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much for your answer. But unfortunately, the problem persists: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: emailvalid.SynCheck.isValid(emailvalid.SynCheck)
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Unknown Source).      I've tried to put Method[] m = c.getDeclaredMethods(); instead and when I printed m[0], the result was "isValid". But as soon as I use c.getDeclaredMethod("isValid") or c.getDeclaredMethod("isValid", Syncheck.class), the error still is exactly the same. Do you have an idea, what else could be wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I got it to work now: getMethod() needs another parameter. This worked for me:    Method m = c.getMethod("isValid", String.class);  Thanks for your help!